# Can't set ListView Adapter from AsyncThread

Tags: android

I'm using a `ListView` on my `Activity` and it takes a while to load from a SQLite DB, so I wanted to show a `ProgressDialog` to the user to let them know something is loading.  I tried to run the task on a separate thread but I'm getting a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.  Here's my main `Activity` code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    try
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
        setContentView(R.layout.open_issues);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        //Set Window title.
        final TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTitle);
        if (title != null)
            title.setText("Open Issues");

        //Call Async Task to run in the background.
        new LoadIssuesTask().execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Errors.LogError(e);
    }
}
```

And the LoadIssuesTask code:

```
private class LoadIssuesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    ProgressDialog pdDialog = null;
   protected void onPreExecute()
   {
       try
       {
           pdDialog = new ProgressDialog(OpenIssues.this);
           pdDialog.setMessage("Loading Issues and Activities, please wait...");
           pdDialog.show();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Errors.LogError(e);
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
       LoadIssues();
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Cursor c) {
       pdDialog.dismiss();
       pdDialog = null;
   }
 }
```

And the LoadIssues code:

```
private void LoadIssues(){
    //Set listview of Issues.
    ListView lvIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvIssues);
    lvIssues.setOnItemClickListener(viewIssuesListener);

    IssueCreator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, Integer.parseInt(AppPreferences.mDBVersion));
    IssueCreator.open();
    lvIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, IssueCreator.queryAll()));        
    IssueCreator.close();
}
```

Constructor for IssueInfoAdapter:

```
public IssueInfoAdapter(Context c, List<IssueInfo> list){
    mListIssueInfo = list;

    //create layout inflater.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
```

It's throwing the error on the .setAdapter method inside `LoadIssues()`.
ERROR:

```
03-12 10:41:23.174: E/AndroidRuntime(11379): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to access the views in the `doInBackground` method that doesn't run on the main `UI` thread. You'll have to set your adapter in the method `onPostExecute` that runs on the `UI` thread:

```
@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<IsueInfo> items) {
       pdDialog.dismiss();
       ListView lvIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvIssues);
       lvIssues.setOnItemClickListener(viewIssuesListener);
       lvIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, items));
   }
```

and in your `doInBackground` method:

```
    @Override
       protected List<IssueInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            IssueCreator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, Integer.parseInt(AppPreferences.mDBVersion));
        IssueCreator.open();

        IssueCreator.close();
        return IssueCreator.queryAll();

   }
```

Also your AsyncTask should be:

```
private class LoadIssuesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<IssueInfo>>
```

Answer (score -3):

In `private void LoadIssues` method call `handler.setMessage(0)` and create a `private Handler` instance to call `setAdapter` method

Use `Handler` instead of `Asynctask`.